# php exec vbs script works only first time in a loop

Tags: php, excel, vbscript, exec, windows-scripting

I am making script to convert excel files into csv files. Excel files are in downloads folder and start with "START". Only the first file is converted and then php is still running, but nothing happens. Running it from browser I can see the circle is running eternally, like loading the website. This is the code:

```
$path = "C:\Users\\tom\Downloads\\";


foreach(glob($path."*.xls") as $excel_file) {
    $substr = substr($excel_file, 24, 5);
    if($substr = "START") {
        $csv_file = str_replace(".xls", ".csv", $excel_file);
        exec("$path"."csv.vbs $excel_file $csv_file");
    }
}
```

the script I am using is `csv.vbs` script and the code is:

```vb
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error! Please specify the source path and the destination. Usage: XlsToCsv SourcePath.xls Destination.csv"
    Wscript.Quit
End If
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
oBook.SaveAs WScript.Arguments.Item(1), 6
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
WScript.Echo "Done"
```

using `shell_exec` is the same. What is wrong here?

Comment: Any spaces in your file names?

Comment: @TimWilliams no spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the last line in `csv.vbs`

```
WScript.Echo "Done"
```

and it's working fine

Comment: if the wscript.echo was your issue then your computer is set to use WScript as the default script host (which is the default) and is popping a message box (even though you might not be able to see it, check your task manager for unused wscript processes). If you want to continue to use wscript.echo in your scripts, either use `cscript csv.vbs` when calling your script (and every script subsequently). Or run `cscript //H:CScript` at a command prompt to change the default script host on your computer to cscript.

Answer (score 1):

$substr is not equal to "START" according to php.net

```
substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

and START is the 5 characters so

```
$substr = substr($excel_file, 0, 5);
```

and there is a wrong comparison try

```
if($substr = "START")
```

the right comparison is by using == or === for strict comparison

```
if($substr == "START")
```

Comment: you are right about the comparison, but it wasn't the reason. Ill give you upvote